# How to obtain translations vector in periodic tiling

Tags: tiling, tessellations

A tiling of the plane, $\mathcal{T}$, is a family of sets- called tiles- that cover the plane without gaps or overlaps. Assume that tiles are regular polygons and tiling is edge-to-edge.

A tiling is said to be periodic when there are two linearly independent translations for which the tiling is invariant.

I am studying about periodic tiling with regular polygons, but I do not know how to obtain  two linearly independent translations in the periodic tiling?

I am so thankful if you help me or introduce a reference for it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What information do you have and what do you need to work out?

Comment: Show us the tiling(s) you are working on.

Comment: See the papers [An integer representation for periodic tilings of the plane by regular polygons](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cag.2021.01.007) and [Acquiring periodic tilings of regular polygons from images](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00371-019-01665-y)